# How to replace the string with other in the whole string

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I am having a string

```
        var countries = india*australia*pakistan*...
        var replace = countries.replace("*",",");
```

then it will give the string as

```
        replace = india,australia*pakistan*...
```

I want to replace all * with , .how can i do that with jquery or javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
result = original.replace(/\*/g, ',');
```

JavaScript's [`String#replace`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.11) function can accept either a string or a regular expression for the first argument. If it's a string, the replacement only happens for the first match. If it's a regular expression, it'll be the first match or all of them if you specify the `g` flag (global).

The regular expression is `\*`, which means "match a literal `*`" (you need the backslash because otherwise `*` is special to the regular expression).

Answer (score 3):

You need Regular Expression with global (g) flag:

```
var replace = countries.replace(/\*/g,",");
```

http://www.regextester.com/jssyntax.html

Answer (score 0):

Might be overkill in your case, but if you plan to do this kind of thing lots of times, consider this:

```
RegExp.escape = function(str) {
    return (str+'').replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");
};

String.prototype.replaceAll = function(string, replacement) {
    return this.replace(new RegExp(RegExp.escape(string), "g"), replacement);
};

console.log("This*is*a*test".replaceAll("*", " ")); // logs 'This is a test'
```

Also takes care of escaping the search string (hence the definition for `RegExp.escape`), so you are free to put anything as the first argument to `replaceAll`